# Loading next imageview in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uiscrollview

I put uiscrollview and set,

```
self.scrollViewHor.directionalLockEnabled = NO;
```

now i've both vertical and horizontal scrolling enabled. 
My problem is, When i scroll horizontal, i want to get the top image
on next frame,

ex; when i scroll from 1.a to 1.b vertically and then scroll to right horizontally , i want 
to see the image 2.a not 2.b..

```
--------------   -------------- 
- Image 1.a  -   - Image 2.a  -
--------------   --------------
--------------   --------------
- Image 1.b  -   - Image 2.b  -
--------------   --------------
--------------   --------------
- Image 1.c  -   - Image 2.c  -
--------------   --------------
```

Comment: just set the contentOffset of scrollView while doing horizontal scrolling.

Comment: is there any method for finding type of scrolling? horizontal or vertical?

Comment: There is no method for this but you can get it by checking content offset in scrollViewDidScroll delegate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you right, ...

Use scroll views within scroll views.

A large scrollview in the background should not be higher than the screen/visible part of the scroll view. It has horizontal scrolling enabled only.
It contains two (or more - for your example two) scroll views. One for each column. Those scroll views have vertical scrolling enabled only.

Doing so you should get everything out of the box. For free actually.

Comment: actually i tried it, but i need to scroll horizontally on every row, not just on top. also if i can do it with one scrollview it will be better.

Comment: Well, in that case create it dynamically. The principle would be the same as for an "endless" scroll view. Assuming just one image is visible at a time. Then create a scroll view of the size of 3x3 images. (If the user currently sees the top left corner, your 1.a, then there wold be only 4). The centered imgae is the one that is always visible. And place the neighbours next to it That is one above, one below, one left and one right (unless of course, there is none).

Comment: (cont.) And when the user scrolls fetch the scroll events and re-align the images. Assuming the user scrolled from 1c to the right. 2a would be visible accoring to your design. Then you re-allign the scroll view in that way, that the centered image is visible again. And you place 2a in the center. Left of it would be 1c (or 1a if you prefer that) and right of it would be 3a and below it would be 2b. Let the user scroll to 2b then again you center the scroll view and put 2b in the midde and 1a(orc) and 3a next to it, 2a above and 2c below, etc. pp.

Comment: ok i will try that. thank you. if i couldnt i thnk i could try to do it with 2 scrollviews like u said before.

Comment: Well, what I said before was more than 2 scrollviews. It was one underying scroll view and one for each column on top of that. That makes 3 in total for your example.

Comment: i put one horizontal scrollview to top and add vertical scrollviews as a child to it. and it is working now. thank you.